# Conditional Caching in Jquery : IF-MODIFIED-SINCE returns 304 response but doesn't load from Cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, jsonp

There is a requirement for us to implement conditional caching on a  jsonp file : Idea is if this JSONP file is modified it needs to be reloaded in the cient cache, we started using the "If-Modified-SINCE" header as below, so far its working good we are able to see If-Modified-Since header in the request using fiddler , and it does returns the 304 response if the date is greater than the jsonp file Last modified date. But for every 304 response it doesn't load the jsonp file data from cache, it just blank. but cached version does exists.

Is there any way we can say that if status is 304, load from cache (we are using IIS5.0 Client: IE 8) ?
and jquery calls doesn't even store the call's date and time it just uses the same date as in header all the time

Below is the sample code snippet,donno the way we are using is wrong or its not supported please help me out to get out of this puzzle :

```js
var myUrl = 
$.ajax({
  url: "something.jsonp",
    var myUrl = 
    $.ajax({
      url: "something.jsonp",
      type:"GET",
      cache: true,
      ifModified: true,
      callback: headerCallback,
      Async: true,
      beforeSend(xhr){
      xhr.setrequestheader("If-Modifed-Since","Wed, 13 Aug 2014 10:09:19 GMT");

    },
      success: function(a){
       a.body(..........),
       LoadAllMyData()
      }
    });
```

Comment: Heads up for anyone who has a problem still: `xhr.setrequestheader("If-Modifed-Since","Wed, 13 Aug 2014 10:09:19 GMT");` isn't `If-Modifed-Since` typo? Maybe change it to `If-Modified-Since`?